# Permutations using coefficient method

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I had a question which is as follows:Number of words of 4 letters formed using the word IITJEE.The book says the answer as coefficient of $x^4$ in  4!$\mathrm{[1+ \frac {x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}]}^{2}[1+x]^2$.My question is where did this  $\mathrm{[1+ \frac {x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}]}^{2}$ come from?

Comment: see exponential generating functions.

Comment: $\mathrm{[1+ \frac {x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}]}^{2}$ means the generating function for 2 I's and 2 E's here, as they are alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The individual factors account for the number of each distinct letter:
$$4!\overbrace{\left(1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\right)}^{2 \times \text{I}}\overbrace{\left(1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\right)}^{2 \times \text{E}}\overbrace{\left(1+\frac{x}{1!}\right)}^{\text{T}}\overbrace{\left(1+\frac{x}{1!}\right)}^{\text{J}}$$

For example, if we have $1$ letter I in the $4$-letter word, it's accounted for by the $x$ term in the first factor: this uses up one of the $x$'s in $x^4$ (informally).  If we instead have $2$ letter Is in the $4$-letter word, then this is instead counted by $x^2$ term in the first factor, using up two of the $x$'s in $x^4$.

Given four letters, there's $4!$ (not necessarily distinct) ways of ordering them, and we divide by $k!$ for each letter we have $k$ copies of to account for non-distinct orderings (whence the coefficients).  This essentially recovers the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

Comment: We divide by k! because we are using exponential generating function rather than linear generating function, because it will account for permutations, as linear accounts for combinations.